# Combine two series as new one in dataframe?

Tags: pandas, series

```
type(x)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
x.shape
(18, 12)
```

To reference the first row and 3:5 columns with expression:

```
type(x.iloc[0,3:5])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
x.iloc[0,3:5]
total_operating_revenue            NaN
net_profit                 3.43019e+07
Name: 2001-12-31, dtype: object
```

To reference the first row and 8:10 columns with expression:

```
type(x.iloc[0,8:10])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
x.iloc[0,8:10]
total_operating_revenue_parent    5.05e+8
net_profit_parent                 4.4e+07
Name: 2001-12-31, dtype: object
```

I want to get the combined new series (suppose it `y`)as following:

```
type(y)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
y.shape
(4,)
```

`y` contains:

```
total_operating_revenue            NaN
net_profit                 3.43019e+07
total_operating_revenue_parent    5.05e+8
net_profit_parent                 4.4e+07
Name: 2001-12-31, dtype: object
```

My failed tries:

```
x.iloc[0,[3:5,8:10]]
x.iloc[0,3:5].combine(x.iloc[0,8:10])
```

`pd.concat([x.iloc[0,3:5],x.iloc[0,8:10]],axis=1)` is not my expect,totally differ from `y`.

```
z = pd.concat([x.iloc[0,3:5],x.iloc[0,8:10]],axis=1)
type(z)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
z.shape
(4, 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake to previously suggest you concat along the columns.
Instead you should concat along the rows:

```
y = pd.concat([x.iloc[0,3:5],x.iloc[0,8:10]])
```

Example:

```
import numpy as np

x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(18, 12)),
                 columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKL'))
```

And then:

```
In [392]: y = pd.concat([x.iloc[0,3:5],x.iloc[0,8:10]])                        

In [393]: y.shape                                                              
Out[393]: (4,)
```